# Xamarin.Android - How do I make an infinite loop in a ViewPager?

Tags: c#, android-viewpager, xamarin.android

I can swipe until I get to the end and then I can only swipe back. I would like to be able to repeat the content, to swipe it indefinitely. I use C# and all the examples I found were in Java.

My code for the adapter is based on [Click on Viewpager Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209015/click-on-viewpager-xamarin-android/33209130#33209130)

Comment: Is there code somewhere that prevents it from swiping to the next image if you are at the end of your image list?  It seems like you would want to reset the `position` variable to the beginning of the list if you try to swipe right when you're at the end of your list.